# InvalidProtocolBufferException when parsing protobuf - invalid tag (zero)

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I have a protobuf message which cribs while being parsed.

I ran the client and server on the same machine and serialized the byte stream.

I compare this with the received byte array using Arrays.equal in java.
It says that they are equal.

My protobuf has just a single fixed32 field storing an IP address.

I used both google protobuf 2.4.1 and 2.5.0 versions with no success. Anything I am missing here?

Stacktrace:

```
com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message contained an invalid tag (zero).
at com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException.invalidTag(InvalidProtocolBufferException.java:89)
at com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream.readTag(CodedInputStream.java:108)
```

...
...

Protobuf Code:

```
message IpMessage {
    required fixed32 ip = 1;
}
```

Compilation:

```
protoc --java_out=. ip-message.proto
```

To parse the message, I use:

```
IpMessage.parseFrom(receivedPkt); //receivedPkt is byte[]
```

Comment: Please show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. (Do you have a short message which you can put in just a `byte[]` for example?)

Comment: @JonSkeet I have updated the question with my code. Please check.

Comment: is the received `byte[]` by any chance an *oversized* buffer, with some spare `0`s at the end? For the record, I would expect that message to be exactly 5 bytes, so either `receivedPkt` should be length `5`, or you need to handle framing etc such that you only try to parse a single (but complete) message at a time

Comment: It is a complete message. The sent length and the received length are equal and Arrays.equal also says they are equal.

Comment: So why don't you show us that in a short but complete program demonstrating the problem? It should just be two lines of code within `main`: `byte[] bytes = ...; IpMessage.parseFrom(bytes);`

Comment: you say it is a complete message: can you confirm, what is the length of `receivedPkt`? Or even better: just show us the exact bytes (hex, base-64, decimal, whatever), and then we will **know** whether it is a valid array containing a well-formed protobuf message.

Comment: @MarcGravell: Please put your comment as answer and I will accept it. That was the root cause.
I ran into the same problem again and remembered this post; excuse me for the late acceptance.

Answer (score 0):

This error appears if your code parses wrong protobuf message at current binary file location. In your case above, current `receivedPkt` isn't a `IpMessage`.